# Optimizing MySql Select for Application

Tags: mysql, database

Iam currently working on an Application thats analyzing the runtime values saved in our database (mean/median for filters like day, month, used method etc.). However I also read that a userfriendly application shouldnt take too long to display data after the user hit a button, but I just cant think of a way to get my query fast for large databases. I thought about writing something that stores the needed values for each day so that they dont need to be calculated again each time a user trys to get the information but with that many filters it just seems to be ways to much information to be stored and I just cant figure out another way..

This is how my SQL Query looks like:

```
SELECT
p.processID, p.runtime, p.servername
FROM
public.process p
WHERE
(p.starttime BETWEEN 1356994800000 AND 1359414000000) AND
p.MainMethodID = '12';
```

EDIT: 
MainMethodID is a BIGINT and I already use indices for "starttime" and "MainMethodID". My question is if there is a ways to get results faster for a GUI application because everything above 5 seconds seems fairly long and I think I can't just calculate everytihing before because of the many filter options (Method used and timeframe) like explained before.

EXPLAIN gives these results:

```
1, 'SIMPLE', 'p', 'ref', 'MainMethodID,startTime', 'MainMethodID', '8', 'const', 28128, 'Using index condition; Using where'
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Please update your question with an `EXPLAIN` of your query.

Comment: The reason this takes too long for you(r taste ;)) is probably an issue with indices. Make sure you have indices for both "starttime" and "MainMethodID" so your where clause can profit of that. If that does not help maybe provide a real number type for MainMethodID instead of a VARCHAR I think that could speed it up also.

Comment: Is `p.MainMethodID` an INT type or a CHAR type?

Comment: 28k records isn't really that many and that query looks like it should be reasonably quick. Is a single execution of that query taking ~5 seconds, or do you have that query in a loop resulting in many executions of it taking 5 seconds?

Comment: I test the execution of the query in the mysql querybrowser so its just 1. I will update my question with a picture of the table if that helps.

Comment: Yes please. That query has nothing obvious that should cause it to be slow

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/wfc2ax2yv/ Here is a link. I can't upload pictures directly yet

Comment: I can't see anything there that should cause a problem. I would question whether idProcess and MainMethodID need to be big ints rather than just INT(11), but that shouldn't cause any real performance issue (very minor change in storage required). You do appear to have a VARCHAR field set as auto inc which is a bit strange. The covering index suggested by Quassnoi should help a bit, but your existing index on MainMethodID probably gives you most of the benefits anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a composite index on `(MainMethodId, startTime)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just tried this but it doesnt seem to improve the speed. Maybe the sql query cant get any fast since it needs to go over ~28000 rows?